# How do I prevent mod_rewrite from treating the URL like a directory?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^edit/blog/([^/]*)$ /edit?blog=$1 [L]`, trying to redirect `http://foo.bar/edit?blog=foobar` to `http://foo.bar/edit/blog/foobar`. It IS redirecting to the page, but it is also treating the URL as a directory, and the resources (stylesheets, scripts, etc) are unable to be found because of this. How do I prevent this from happening?

**Note**: The rewrite rule says `edit?blog=foobar` and not `edit.php?blog=foobar` because earlier in the .htaccess file, I remove .php extensions. I already tried doing it with the .php extension, but got the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add that in your `edit` html `<head>`:

```
<base href="/">
```

or

```
<base href="http://foo.bar/">
```